# How to extract zcor (working correlation) from geeglm of geepack R

Tags: r

I fitted a model with geeglm from geepack of R(3.2.5) Ubuntu system. Here is my command

```
fga <- geeglm(response~covariates, data=dataframe, id=pid, 
family=binomial, scale.fix=T, corstr='exchangeable')
```

The data is not balanced. different pid groups have from 1 up to 16 measurements. What I want now is to extract the zcor or working correlation matrix of the largest group(the group with 16 measurements). I know this could be down, the result would be a vector instead of matrix but shows pairwise correlations. However, after hours of search, I just could not find a way to do this. I also know if I use gee from gee package, you can get this matrix. But how can we get this working.correlation matrix by using geepack?